# Why Gini index considers a binary split in decision trees?

Tags: binary-tree, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

According to my references (see links below), it seems Gini index considers a binary split in decision trees. Why can't it consider multiway splits?

http://webserver.inf.unibz.it/dis/teaching/DWDM/slides2011/lesson5-Classification-2.pdf

[Example from Google Book Search](https://books.google.lk/books?id=AfL0t-YzOrEC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=gini%20index%20binary%20split%20why&source=bl&ots=Uw_TzVfqy1&sig=g5AltlIkwHL6eiVKgLdxoIkAUK4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXq7qI_JjRAhXEsY8KHWerDqQ4ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=gini%20index%20binary%20split%20why&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, trees are not restricted to binary splits but can also be grown with multiway splits - based on the Gini index or other selection criteria. However, the (locally optimal) search for multiway splits in numeric variables would become much more burdensome. Hence, tree algorithms often rely on greedy forward selection of binary splits where subsequent binary splits in the same variable can also represent multiway splits. For more discussion see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/are-decision-trees-almost-always-binary-trees